# Remove Activity completely Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-finish

I would like to remove my activity from activity stack by activity stack I mean removing it from the list of activities that show up when you press the third button in navigation bar.

I tried the following code but it dint clear from that list:

```
finish();
```

I tried this as well

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

And also this as well (GC)

```
System.runFinalization();
System.exit(0);
```

But my activity still remains in that list. Is there a way to completely remove it ???

Comment: Try to add this in your `Activity` in `manifest` `android:excludeFromRecents="true"`

Comment: @MD Thanks by using android:excludeFromRecents="true" it works. You add it in the answer section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way in your `manifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".Your_Activity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true" ...
```